# How to align three equal horizontal boxes with spaces around them

Tags: html, css, flexbox, zurb-foundation

I want to make three boxes to be next to each other in a row. I'm using Foundation:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
  </div>
</div>
```

I want them to be `width:32%`, and the first one to be on the far left, the second one in the middle and the third one at the very right.

I tried flexbox's `justify-content: space-around` but the outside boxes are not in their right places. I tried columns but the middle one floats left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with the `justify-content: space-between` because its purpose is to do exactly what you'd like to achieve:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.box {
  flex: 0 0 32%;
  height: 20px;
  background: Aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use flex and use margin auto to make the first and last element stuck to the left/right side :

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.box {
  flex: 0 0 32%; /* or simply width:32%; */
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
}

.box:first-child {
  margin-right: auto;
}

.box:last-child {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what I needed, awesome! Just a quick question, what does `flex: 0 0 32%;` do?

Comment: @Al-josh it's almost the same as `width:32%` here i simply said it should take 32% of the length (you can read more about here : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-basis.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You could use **Flexbox** like follow:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
}
.box {
  width: 32%;
  flex: 1;
  background: red;
  height: 150px;
  margin-right: 20px; /* You can change it to increase/decrease the space between boxes */
}
.box:last-child {
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
  </div>
</div>
```

They will be aligned vertically and horizontally.

Comment: **the first one to be on the far left, the second one in the middle and the third one at the very right.**

Comment: and this is exactly what they are acting

Comment: add border to `row` and see ... you have margin-right so the third one will never be at the very right.

Comment: you just quote his words while you could simply improve my answer when you tell me that I have an extra margin right at the last div, anyway thank you for the notice.

Comment: i quoted a part of his world because it's not the only missing part .. the main purpose is to have the div taking 32%  of the width but you added fixed margin which make it incorrect. In this case the div will never be 32% width (they will take (width - total margin)/3 ). Also using flex:1 make the use of width useless in your case. Am sorry to say it but the answer is incorrect (i didn't downvote so you don't get upset)

Comment: thank you for the information, totally I'm not upset.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, add `.box { position: relative; }`. In the first div's style, add `left: 0%;`, in the second div `left: 34%;`, and in the third one `right: 0%;`.